# Popping viewcontroller and then back to RootViewController doesn't seem to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an app that pushes four viewcontrollers on the stack.  In the fourth view controller, I do a PopViewController, so I should be back at the 3rd viewcontroller, and in the viewWillAppear method, I do a PopToRootViewController.  This does not get me back to the first viewcontroller correctly.  The code is straightforward, just a

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES]
```

in each of the first 3 viewcontrollers, and in the fourth

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES].
```

In the 3rd viewcontroller, I have a viewWillAppear method which does:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES].
```

---

As I go through the views, I get the following:

Start app:

```
         Back:               Title: FirstLevel
```

Press OK:

```
         Back: FirstLevel    Title: SecondLevel
```

Press OK:

```
         Back: SecondLevel   Title: ThirdLevel
```

Press OK:

```
         Back: ThirdLevel    Title: FourthLevel
```

Press OK: which pops back 1 and then pops back to root:

```
         Back: FirstLevel    Title: ThirdLevel
```

If I press OK now:

```
         Back: ThirdLevel    Title: SecondLevel
```

I'm sorry if this is confusing.  Should I be able to pop back one view controller and then immediately pop back to the root?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by Mark, you should use `-popToRootViewController` from your 4rth view controller, instead of 3rd view controller, as your motive is to pop it to root view controller.

**BUT** if you still want to achieve this functionalty for some anonymous reason, then in the 3rd viewcontroller, use :

`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]` in `viewDidAppear` method, instead of `viewWillAppear`.

I hope it works :)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be any reason to pop back to view controller 3, since you're trying to go to the root before view controller 3's view even appears. Just send `-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` to view controller 4.

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do is get some information from the user with the fourth view controller.  Then I dismiss that view controller, and I may or may not have to get more information.  If I have all the info, then I wanted to go back to the root view controller; otherwise, I was going to push another view controller to get more information.  I suppose I could pass information to the fourth view controller to go push a fifth for more info, etc. and then finally pop to root after I have everything I need.

Comment: Putting the call in viewDidAppear seems to work fine, however, I do get to see that other view for an instance, which doesn't look very professional.  Is there any way around that other than changing the architecture?

Comment: From a UX standpoint, pushing a 5th controller for more information would be less confusing to the user.